# Detect port scanning on all ports

Tags: python

I am looking to create a Python script that alerts me when any port (all) on my computer is touched/interacted with. I have absolutely no clue where to start so any resource that could point me in the right direction would be greatly appreciated.

I want to use a Rasberry Pi 3. `(Edit: Sorry for not including this)`

Comment: You need to specify what OS are you interested in. The answers will be very different for each case.

Comment: @viraptor thanks for letting me know :)

Answer (score 1):

Depends on what you need from the solution, you can use:

- for testing and if you don't mind packets missing when you process them too slow: https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pcapy
- if you want to react to the packets in any way: forward the packets from the iptables to NFQUEUE and process using https://pypi.python.org/pypi/NetfilterQueue